# FragmentTabHosts-Tab content is added on every click on the tab

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I have a FragmentTabHost with 4 tabs. The content of one tab is created dynamically in the `onViewCreated` method. It's a table and the amount of rows added to this table depends on the user settings.

My problem is, when I add (for testing purposes) 3 rows to the table, switch the tab and switch back, I have 6 rows in the table. If I do it again, I have 9 rows in the table.

So everytime I open this tab 3 rows are added to the table without the former content being deleted.

If I got it right, the FragmentTabHost stores the state of each Tabs Fragment. So I check if the `savedInstanceState` of the `onViewCreated` method is null before adding the rows. Unfortunately `savedInstanceState` always returns null.

This is the initialization code of my FragmentTabHost

```
private void initTabs()
{
    FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),R.id.realtabcontent);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("tab1"), TestFragment1.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("tab2"), TestFragment2.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("tab3"), TestFragment3.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("tab4"), TestFragment4.class, null);     

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}
```

This is the code of the 'tableView'-Fragment of one of the tabs:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_tableview, container, false);    
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Log.d("savedInstanceState", String.valueOf(savedInstanceState)); // is always null

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        return;

    // Add Test-Rows
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        RowFragment fragment = new RowFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.RowFragmentLayoutContainer, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

}

What is wrong with my code? What must I do to only add the rows once?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the way you are using the child fragments looks a bit weird, but in case you have a reason to use fragments as table items (who am I to judge :) ), the simplest way that I can quickly come up with is to first try and find the fragment in case it was previously added:

```
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
if (manager.findFragmentById(R.id.RowFragmentLayoutContainer) != null)
    return;

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    RowFragment fragment = new RowFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.RowFragmentLayoutContainer, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). But shouldn't be savedInstanceState != null or the view completly new created? There must be another way than looking for formely added rows... or not :)?

Comment: I've never needed to use the savedInstanceState, but I've thought that you need to store something yourself in `onSaveInstanceState` in order to have the state available when the fragment is created again. Someone correct me if I'm wrong, though. But what I suggested is just a simple way to (hopefully) get the thing working. Like I said, using the fragments for table rows seems like an overkill, maybe you could use a `ListView` instead and just update its adapter  in the tab fragment's `onResume`?

Comment: I try to port an iOS-app to android and I still have my problems to get several thinks done right in android ;). Thanks for the tip with the ListView. I'll take a look at it. Right now I've solved my problem with using a bool-var. But I still have my doubts that this is the right way to handle my issue. Android feels some kind of weird, when you come from iOS :).

Comment: This might help you with the `ListView`s in case you decide to use them (read the whole tutorial if you can, there's a lot of good things to learn): http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. That seems to be a far better approach than using fragments :). And I also have click events etc included :). So, I'll port my code to ListView ;)... Thanks!